# View/open file url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view that creates a document with a Title, Date, and name of file that I upload. Once that document is created it is returned to a View that shows the document that I just created and is stored in a database.

Here is the code that creates the document:

```
   <form asp-action="CreateDirectorDocument" role="form" class="form- 
  horizontal">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="alert- 
      danger text-danger"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-10"><a asp- 
        action="Index">View Documents</a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-10"><label asp-for="Date"> 
          </label></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2"><input asp-for="Date" /> 
           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-2"><label asp- 
            for="DocFile"></label></div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input asp-for="DocFile" type="file" 
                multiple>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-2"><label asp-for="Title"> 
            </label></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2"><input asp-for="Title" 
           /></div>
                        </div>


         </form>
```

View that is return after document has been created:

```
           <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-md-2" style="border-bottom: solid"> 
             </th>

                        <th class="col-md-2" style="border-bottom: 
                solid">Title</th>

                        <th class="col-md-2" style="border-bottom: 
                solid">Date</th>

                        <th class="col-md-2" style="border-bottom: solid"> 
            </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var dirDocs in Model.Docs)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-md-2">
                                <a asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Docs" 
            asp-action="EditDirectorDocument" asp-route- 
            id="@dirDocs.Id">Edit</a>
                                <a asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Docs" 
            asp-action="DeleteDirectorDocument" asp-route- 
           returnViewName="@returnViewName" asp-route-id="@dirDocs.Id" 
              onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete 
              this document?');">Delete</a>
                            </td>

                            <td class="col-md-2">@dirDocs.Title</td>

                            <td class="col-md-2">@dirDocs.Date</td>

                            <td class="col-md-2"><a asp-route- 
                      id="@dirDocs.Url" target="_blank">Open</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    }

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

The file that is uploaded gets stored as a document file and is created as a url for the user to view. How do I do this in MVC. Is that set up in the controller? If so how is that done?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think you just need:

```
<a href="@dirDocs.Url" target="_blank">Open</a>
```

Instead of

```
<a asp-route-id="@dirDocs.Url" target="_blank">Open</a>
```

I assume you mean you get a URL back from the upload process that you want to display to the user so they can click on it and see the file they uploaded.

If you wanted to display some thing like that inline you could probably use an iframe whose src is set to @dirDocs.Url:

```
<iframe src="@dirDocs.Url"></iframe>
```

Comment: Do I need anything in the controller?

Comment: If it's a URL that's not using your controller then no

Comment: I tried <a href="@dirDocs.Url" target="_blank">Open</a> and it makes it into a non-link. It isn't a link anymore.

Comment: Make sure that `dirDocs.Url` isn't null because in my experience that's usually what that means. Also, try putting a breakpoint in the razor view on that line and see what the value is

Comment: @bootsy let me know if that worked and if it did remember to upvote my answer ;-)